# What indications are there that a muscular adaptation has been triggered?

Tags: exercise, workout, routine

There is plenty of discussion around optimal sets/reps for various types of adaptations to be triggered.

If someone is interested only in maintenance, or a minimal workout, they might want to know what is the minimum amount of work needed to trigger an adaptation.

About this amount, I'm wondering is there a **physical sign** that **guarantees it has occurred**?

For example, suppose I load up 70% of my 1RM and start doing reps, and will do only set until one of the following occur.

1. muscle pump
2. muscle burn
3. shaking / instability during a rep
4. inability to perform another rep

Are any of those an indicator that I have achieved a minimal level of work to maintain muscle or possibly grow more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somewhat overly simplistic and assumes that if there were an evidenced base solution, it would be the **same** for everyone.  That's not the case.

I like to think of adaptation as a synergistic, complicated process that requires more than just weight training.  Neglecting all other aspects (eg. Nutrition, recovery, genetics, etc.) that contribute to the process is a mistake.  You must also consider additional factors that contribute to adaptation: [overload, specificity, reversibility, and individual differences](http://www.sportsci.org/encyc/adaptex/adaptex.html).  Thus, looking for a guaranteed “physical sign” from the list you provided is not possible in my opinion.  They are simply indicators of  possible different reactions to training resistance.  For example, the “*pump*” occurs as “[a compensatory increase of blood pressure forces plasma from the congested capillaries into the interstitial spaces of the muscle cells](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/PumpBurn.html).  And, similarly, the “*burn*” is a result of lactic acid build up in the muscle.  Neither is an indicator that adaptation has occurred.

I think of  adaptation as a moving target.  Especially for experienced trainers. Once it has occurred, there typically needs to be a subtle change in the training regime to force it occur in the future.  Otherwise, improvement is stagnant.  I would rather look at the accumulated effect of training (over several months/years) as an indicator of success.  Especially, if one plans to train for many years to come.